# Handling form element relations based on a matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I would like to hear your opinions and ideas about how to solve a task I have encountered about a form with a little complex behavior.

Imagine a search form which contains approx. 30 input elements /text, select, checkbox, etc./ which dynamically change during the user's input process. E.g. if you change the first select, some fields must change to be hidden, some fields must change to be required, etc. The field relations are mapped in a matrix in an Excel from which the backend will process this information and provide it for the frontend - me. The generated form fields can be provided by custom classes/data attributes and I might get a JSON with the relations and process everything on my own from that point. These relations will probably change in the future, or at least the application must be ready for that, so that also needs to take into consideration. JQuery is available and also I can use some Angular/Backbone type framework if neeeded.

I am a junior frontend developer and to be honest, I havent come up with a solid solution yet, so I would appreciate every thought-provoking input :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: "Imagine a [widget]" is almost never a good question. Can you provide an example of what your "matrix" data will look like? Parsing and applying rules from imaginary data is, uh, _tricky_.

Comment: Get a piece of paper and make a table with mutliple columns. In the first column, write down the name of the first element. In the second column, write down the names of elements that will trigger the display of this element (call this column requiredFor). In the third column, write down the names of elements that will trigger the hiding of this element (call this column hiddenFor). In the fourth column, write down the names of elements that must contain valid if this element is visible (call it dependsOn). Generate this from the excel and make javascript to create the form & logic on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've defined the relations from the point of view of the input elements that are affected by these relations. This structure allows for some more flexibility including support for checking the values of multiple select boxes and to use logic similar to `AND` and `OR` statements. Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/bxTLR/.

This code starts with a Javascript object which contains the definition of the relations, which you might fetch with an AJAX-call which returns JSON. It then processes this information into data attributes of the input elements and attaches a listener to the `change` event of the select boxes.

Relations defined for `input1`:

- `input1` is required if `select1` is **value1**
- `input1` is hidden if `select1` is **value2**

Relations defined for `input2`:

- `input2` is required if `select2` is **value2**  or `select2` is **value3**
- `input2` is hidden if `select3` is **value2**  or `select3` is **value3**

Relations defined for `input3`:

- `input3` is required if `select1` is **value1** and `select2` is **value1** and `select3` is **value2**
- `input3` is hidden if `select1` is **value2** and `select2` is **value2** and `select3` is **value1**

Relations defined for `input4`:

- `input4` is required if `select1` is **value1** and `select2` is **value2** and `select3` is **value1**
- `input4` is hidden if `select1` is **value2** and `select2` is **value1** and `select3` is **value2**

Relations defined for `input5`:

- `input5` is required if (`select1` is **value1** and (`select2` is **value1** or `select2` is **value2**) and (`select3` is **value1** or `select3` is **value2**)) or (`select1` is **value1** and `select3` is **value3**)
- `input5` is hidden if (`select1` is **value2** and (`select2` is **value1** or `select2` is **value2**) and (`select3` is **value1** or `select3` is **value2**)) or (`select1` is **value2** and `select3` is **value3**)

HTML select boxes:

```
<div>
    <label>Select 1</label>
    <select id="select1" class="trigger">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Select 2</label>
    <select id="select2" class="trigger">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Select 3</label>
    <select id="select3" class="trigger">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

HTML input elements:

```
<div>
    <label>Input 1</label>
    <input id="input1" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Input 2</label>
    <input id="input2" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Input 3</label>
    <input id="input3" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Input 4</label>
    <input id="input4" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Input 5</label>
    <input id="input5" type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.required input {
    border-color: #f00;
}
div.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JSON for the relations:

```
var relationsJSON = {
    "input1": {
        requiredIf: [{
            "select1": ["value1"]
        }],
        hiddenIf: [{
            "select1": ["value2"]
        }]
    },
    "input2": {
        requiredIf: [{
            "select2": ["value2", "value3"]
        }],
        hiddenIf: [{
            "select3": ["value2", "value3"]
        }]
    },
    "input3": {
        requiredIf: [{
            "select1": ["value1"],
            "select2": ["value1"],
            "select3": ["value2"]
        }],
        hiddenIf: [{
            "select1": ["value2"],
            "select2": ["value2"],
            "select3": ["value1"]
        }]
    },
    "input4": {
        requiredIf: [{
            "select1": ["value1"],
            "select2": ["value2"],
            "select3": ["value1"]
        }],
        hiddenIf: [{
            "select1": ["value2"],
            "select2": ["value1"],
            "select3": ["value2"]
        }]
    },
    "input5": {
        requiredIf: [{
            "select1": ["value1"],
            "select2": ["value1", "value2"],
            "select3": ["value1", "value2"]
        }, {
            "select1": ["value1"],
            "select3": ["value3"]
        }],
        hiddenIf: [{
            "select1": ["value2"],
            "select2": ["value1", "value2"],
            "select3": ["value1", "value2"]
        }, {
            "select1": ["value2"],
            "select3": ["value3"]
        }]
    }
};
```

Javascript functions:

```
function storeRelation($input, relationName, relation) {
    var requiredIfOutput = [];
    var requiredIfClasses = [];
    $.each(relation, function(index, condition) {
        var conditionOutput = [];
        $.each(condition, function(selectID, values) {
            requiredIfClasses.push(relationName + '-' + selectID);
            conditionOutput.push('"' + selectID + '":["' + values.join('","') + '"]');
        });
        requiredIfOutput.push('{' + conditionOutput.join(',') + '}');
    });
    $input.addClass(requiredIfClasses.join(' '));
    $input.attr('data-' + relationName, '[' + requiredIfOutput.join(',') + ']');
}

function testRelation($input, relationName) {
    var requiredIfData = $.parseJSON($input.attr('data-' + relationName));
    var hasValidCondition = false;
    $.each(requiredIfData, function(index, condition) {
        var isValidCondition = true;
        $.each(condition, function(selectID, values) {
            var hasValidValue = false;
            var $requiredIfSelect = $('#' + selectID);
            $.each(values, function(index, value) {
                if ($requiredIfSelect.val() == value) {
                    hasValidValue = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (!hasValidValue) {
                isValidCondition = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (isValidCondition) {
            hasValidCondition = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return hasValidCondition;
}
```

Javascript document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.each(relationsJSON, function(inputID, relations) {
        var $input = $('#' + inputID);
        if (relations.requiredIf != 'undefined') {
            storeRelation($input, 'required-if', relations.requiredIf);
        }
        if (relations.hiddenIf != 'undefined') {
            storeRelation($input, 'hidden-if', relations.hiddenIf);
        }
    });

    $('select.trigger').each(function() {
        var $select = $(this);
        $select.on('change', function() {

            var $requiredIfInputs = $('.required-if-' + $select.attr('id'));
            $requiredIfInputs.each(function() {
                var $input = $(this);
                var $container = $input.parent();
                if (testRelation($input, 'required-if')) {
                    $container.addClass('required');
                } else {
                    $container.removeClass('required');
                }
            });

            var $hiddenIfInputs = $('.hidden-if-' + $select.attr('id'));
            $hiddenIfInputs.each(function() {
                var $input = $(this);
                var $container = $input.parent();
                if (testRelation($input, 'hidden-if')) {
                    $container.addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $container.removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });

        });
        $select.trigger('change');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the thing I was looking for.